# Flutter macOS high Sierra error

Tags: configuration, flutter, macos-high-sierra

I follow the instruction on Flutter site. Flutter Doctor warning is below. My problem I don't know how to overcome from this error, warning etc.

Any help please?

```
/Users/niyazitoros/development/flutter/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale tr-TR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
    ✗ Missing Xcode dependency: Python module "six".
      Install via 'pip install six' or 'sudo easy_install six'.
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not initialized.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.io/platform-plugins
      To initialize CocoaPods, run:
        pod setup
      once to finalize CocoaPods' installation.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

After correcting the flutter path doctor gives me this warning.

```
/Users/niyazitoros/development/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale tr-TR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
    ✗ Missing Xcode dependency: Python module "six".
      Install via 'pip install six' or 'sudo easy_install six'.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: For Android you need to install Android Studio and for iOS XCode

Comment: Have you actually tried doing what the flutter doctor is saying? To accept the android license, install six and initialize cocoapods?

Comment: I did install xCode full and Android Studio full about month ago. Problem was the flutter folder was in download folder. I correct the path and now is working with 1 warning. Cannot install six.

Comment: user-MBP:~ user$ easy_install -U six
Searching for six
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/
Couldn't find index page for 'six' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or working download links found for six
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('six')

Comment: after clean install macOS high Sierra makes everything perfect. I follow the steps from macOS installation and its working now.

Comment: Did you try to accept the android licenses and `pip install six` as mentioned in the `flutter doctor` output?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. Thanks is working now.

Comment: I do have the same problem, only with installing 'six', when I try to install it terminal says the requirement already satisfied. But flutter doctor can't identify any 'six'. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to fix the android SDK licence error go on your terminal and type

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

then

```
pip install six
```

if the error still persists run

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I tried the upgrade, didnt work though. Any fresh ideas?

Comment: I had another MacBook and had similar problems. Clean install and step by step helps me on that. https://flutter.io/setup-macos/

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still have the problem with pip six[image]

Uninstall python2

`brew uninstall python@2`
this one is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix android SDK license by using

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

next you run

```
pip install six
```